# Android Studio listview, intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I am making a pretty simple app which displays 100 random numbers, and when a number is clicked in the list view, it launches a web browser. I am pretty sure I have everything done and working, but is there anyway to tie the same intent to each number/position in the list? Besides a switch statement? I will do a switch statement if needed, but 100 numbers is a lot. Haha. For the life of me I cannot figure out what to do. Would a loop work? I have only been using Android Studio for about two months.Thanks in advance for all your help.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){

    switch ( position ) {
        case 0: String link = "https://duckduckgo.com/";
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(link);
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(viewIntent);
    }

    String link = "https://duckduckgo.com/";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(link);


    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(viewIntent);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_assignment4);

    ListView ListViewNumbers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewNumbers);


    Random ran = new Random();
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>(100);
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            Integer r = ran.nextInt();
            nums.add(r);
        }

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.num_list_layout, nums);
    ListViewNumbers.setAdapter(adapter);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_assignment4, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: You mean each item have a different uri?

Comment: Each item can have the same uri, I just need a way to set the intent for all of the 100 numbers without having to type out the 100 cases. Haha.

Comment: If the intent will be same,why don'tyou create an intent inadvance and start it on onItemClick.

Comment: @BHP90 all items have the same url, so why do you care about position number? why don't you just start new intent on onItemClick event without `switch case`?

Comment: This is all a learning experience for me. Haha. I appreciate your guys help. If I declare the intent with the url/uri in the onItemClick it will launch the webpage when a listview is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use default in your switch case? Here is the code for you

```
  switch ( position ) {
        case 0: String link = "https://duckduckgo.com/";
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(link);
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(viewIntent);
            break;
        default:   
               String link = "https://duckduckgo.com/";
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(link);
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(viewIntent);
          break; 
    }
```

Comment: Would this work so that no matter which item on the listview is clicked it will go to the intent?

Comment: Try it once.. Whats there to loose?

Answer (score 0):

How about declaring `string-array` in your `strings.xml` then you can get it as `String[]` and assign it to your `adapter` item. I think it's much easier.

```
<string-array name="uri_list">
    <item>uri1</item>
    <item>uri2</item>
    ....
    <item>uri100</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare a `string-array` in your `strings.xml`
Each item is an url. And rely on the position from `onItemClick`, you can extract the url from string array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {// put de code if you intent here thats all } });
```